# Why in this question are the intervals considered countable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am just learning real analysis:
[image: Solution in question I am confused on]

I don't understand why these open intervals in the solution are considered countable. I thought that any interval $(a,b)$ maps into $\mathbb R$. Wouldn't then any open interval be considered uncountable, since it is implicitly containing members that are not part of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: "a *countable collection* of things" as opposed to "a collection of *countable things*".

Comment: It should probably say $A$ is countable or we have countably many $I\in A$